# How to list all azure container using nodejs or any otherway?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there is any way to list all containers from an Azure storage account?

If it is nodejs means very helpful to me, else please suggest me the way to list all container.

Comment: Have you looked at node SDK for Azure Storage?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Yes i'm using azure-storage Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Node.js, But there is no function provided for list container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try blobService.listContainersSegmented under [azure-storage-node SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) (sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/fda90e2493ccfc83df79678d602008fb4470ae0f/browser/samples/sample-blob.html#L82)).

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers: The referenced [azure-storage-node SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) mentioned at the accepted answer is now old (will be deprecated soon). The new sdk for JS (both for node and browser environments) is called azure-sdk-for-js can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js).

To list all containers, you use the same listContainersSegmented function but now it is a part of the ServiceURL class, and a sample code on how to use it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs-v10) under the section "show containers names".

This documentaition also includes bunch of other basic and useful stuff to do with blobs, so have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [List Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-containers2) operation within the [Blob Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/blob-service-rest-api)

Comment: As per documentation i just open my link in browser https://xxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list,  but result as follows The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:1866db8b-0001-002f-7870-ba6c38000000 Time:2017-04-21T07:29:07.5411678Z

Comment: Is to container public available?